# How can i add text to the menu

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I was trying to add some text to my menu a few hours already .Is there a way to add the text on my website like in the photo?

[How I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwH9H.png)

[My current website](https://halfturned.github.io/)

[WebsiteSource](https://github.com/halfturned/halfturned.github.io)

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/xpkuv08f/ ?

Comment: Man - thank you. you saved my life!!!